# Are there any big-company ads in Esperanto?

Tags: culture

I know there are sometimes ads in Esperanto magazines. What I’m really curious about is: Has any ”big” company ever published an ad in Esperanto?

I’m thinking about multinational brands like Coca-Cola, McDonald’s etc. The bigger the better, in this particular case! ;-) It would be interesting, for example, to see a typical slogan (”Obey your thirst!” etc.) rendered into Esperanto, and to know why the company chose the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the magazino Monato I saw full page ads of Bosch, of Agfa. Maybe it would be a nice job for a rainy day to go through my collection.

Answer (score 6):

When I was at the *Universala Kongreso* in Berlin in 1999, an employee of the company made a big deal about showing me an ad for Bosch in the *Kongresa Libro* or in some other magazine that was easily available at the time. I'm sure this sort of thing is fairly common - that is, common enough that they could be collected into an interesting coffee table book were someone so inclined.

Comment: A coffee table book is a really great idea! :-) Has anyone got enough of these ads to start a collection? (Which could then later be turned into a book.)

Comment: That magazine was Monato. I found the list now of the ads that appeared in Monato:     Agfa-Gevaert, Berthold Bolz, Bosch, GB, Kredietbank, Manfred Schauber, Mitsui & Co, Novotechnik, Siemens, Unitech.
    Willy VOIT GmbH & Co. KG

Answer (score 5):

Littlewoods, which at the time was a popular high street chain in the U.K., ran a TV advert in 2013 which was widely reported to be in Esperanto. I remember some criticism by esperantists online who claimed the dialogue wasn't completely intelligible or syntactically correct, but it did lead to a few stories about Esperanto/ conlangs in mainstream UK media.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, when visiting The Esperanto Village (Herzberg Am Harz) in Germany, I was shown a full collection of professional, full-quality, full-color promotional materials produced by, for example, Fiat--multi-page full-size flyers filled with promotional Esperanto text. It was surreal and quite impressive.

I don't recall all of the companies I saw, unfortunately, and these adds were a bit older--60's or 70's.

Comment: The FIAT material (flyers, a small dictionary of automotive terms, etc.) dates back to the 60's and is to be credited to Giuseppe Grattapaglia, who was then a FIAT employee in Turin. When he left for Bona Espero, FIAT stopped producing anything Esperanto-related.

Comment: Interesting. Vikipedio supports your assertion: https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Grattapaglia

Answer (score 2):

I have seen adds of internationally known flight companies in Esperanto -- in the context of informational material for the Universala Kongreso, as UEA partners with some flight companies for the organization of this event.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a video by British Telecom with Esperanto in it.
This article mentions British Telecom using Esperanto for marketing: [Esperanto wird 125 Jahre alt](https://www.ots.at/presseaussendung/OTS_20120109_OTS0014/esperanto-wird-125-jahre-alt)